# When looting unidentified dyes, can I get a color I already own?

Tags: guild-wars-2

When looting unidentified dyes, can I get a color I already own?  If so, will it consume the dye if I click on it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you identify a dye, what color you get is totally random and will not be affect by what color dyes you have already unlocked.

If however you do get a color that you already have, the dye will say in red text: "You have already unlocked this dye!"

You will NOT be able to accidentally unlock the dye again on an character that has already unlocked that color. If you do try to unlock a color you have already unlocked, you will get a message on your screen that says: "You have already unlocked this dye."

Comment: There is good reason for this. If this were not the case, if you sold a dye, you would be unable to find it again except by purchasing it. If it checked against the dyes you had unlocked, it would be a very trivial matter to purchase all the cheap dyes, and simply continuously sell the more expensive ones, as that would be all you found.

Comment: It also is easier programatically. A random number on the dye generation table is one operation (potentially). Having to iterate through and find an unowned dye is more work. Programmers abide by Occam's Razor whenever possible!